# Angularjs- translate , injector: modulerr error

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angularjs-translate but getting **Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=pharma** error, below is my code for reference

```
var app = angular.module('pharma',['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config('$translateProvider',function($translateProvider){


     $translateProvider.translations('en', {
         "TITLE":"Angular way!"
    });
     $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
         "TITLE":"angulaire !"
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');


});


app.controller('TranslateController',  function($translate, $scope) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
});
```

Comment: Code seems OK, did you include the JS lib in your index.html ?

Comment: These are the lib files included 

<script src="library/js/vendor/angular.js"></script> 
  <script src="library/js/vendor/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <script src="library/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
var app = angular.module('pharma',['pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(function($translateProvider){ 
     $translateProvider.translations('en', {
         "TITLE":"Angular way!"
     });
     $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
         "TITLE":"angulaire !"
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
 });

 app.controller('TranslateController',  ['$translate', '$scope', function($translate, $scope) {
      $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
      };
 }]);
```

Comment: Check code from answer. There're was some erorrs in DI decalarations.

Comment: with your answer i am getting below error now
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pharma due to: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: